# EC2 Ubuntu 10.04 publickey error on a new instance (key works for an existing instance)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

Tried booting through the aws dashboard.

Also tried creating from the command line api tools.

Checked ssh with -vvv and made sure it was trying the key (note that an old instance with the same key is accessible)...

Checked the system log on AWS console (never seems to finish (stuck on keygen for the host) - despite waiting approx. 60m).

System log last line:
    ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
    ec2: #############################################################

System log also contains errors (however I'm led to believe that the error is irrelevant):

```
init: console-setup main process (63) terminated with status 1


    %Ginit: plymouth-splash main process (228) terminated with status 2

init: plymouth main process (45) killed by SEGV signal
```

Comment: Are you using the same AMI for both instances?

Comment: @rob: nope, I haven't tried that using ami-a403f7cd for the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this problem a couple of different times because I messed something up in /etc/fstab that was causing problems on boot (referring to an EBS volume that wasn't mounted, usually). It seems like other people have had the same [misdiagnosed plymouth problem](http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu/msg/909c993eac547808) that masked an fstab snafu.